# Redirecting tail output into a program

Tags: linux, bash, tail

I want to send a program the most recent lines from a text file using tail as stdin.

First, I echo to the program some input that will be the same every time, then send in tail input from an inputfile which should first be processed through sed. The following is the command line that I expect to work. But when the program runs it only receives the echo input, not the tail input.

```
(echo "new" && tail -f ~/inputfile 2> /dev/null | sed -n -r 'some regex' && cat) | ./program
```

However, the following works exactly as expected, printing everything out to the terminal:

```
echo "new" && tail -f ~/inputfile 2> /dev/null | sed -n -r 'some regex' && cat
```

So I tried with another type of output, and again while the echoed text posted, the tail text does not appear anywhere:

```
(echo "new"  && tail -f ~/inputfile 2> /dev/null | sed -n -r 'some regex') | tee out.txt
```

This made me think it is a problem with buffering, but I tried the `unbuffer` program and all other advice here (https://superuser.com/questions/59497/writing-tail-f-output-to-another-file) without results. Where is the tail output going and how can I get it to go into my program as expected?

Comment: Are you sure that sed is printing anything?  `-n` turns off printing the pattern space, so the only output from that command will be what you print explicitly with `p`.  (I think...I don't do a lot with sed.)

Try `cat ~/inputfile | sed -n -r 'some regex'` and see if anything gets printed.  If not, well, you know why!

Comment: In your first two examples, I don't think `cat` ever gets executed.  In all the examples, the shell runs `echo` (which succeeds), so it continues to the second command, the pipeline `tail | sed`.  But `tail -f` never exits -- it just waits for more data to appear at the end of `~/inputfile`.  `sed` may be buffering the output (or there may be no output at all) but until `tail` exits, `sed` won't finish up and exit either.  And until `tail | sed` exits, `cat` won't be executed.  (I don't think you need `cat` at all, really.)
Is some other process appending to `~/inputfile`?

Comment: @DaveM. yes sed is printing a single capture group using that combination. I can assure that it works and is printing something. You're right about cat not getting executed, although removing it doesn't change anything - the pipe still doesn't work. Yes another process is appending to ~/inputfile and I want to send part of that output to my program.

Comment: @DaveM. what I was hoping for by using `&& cat` was to be able to retain stdin by typing in the terminal, but you're right, it doesn't work there. And if I put it at the front then it will likewise stop the tail command from ever executing.

Comment: I've reproduced your problem using a "producer" program that adds data to a file (your `inputfile`), then `(echo Start && tail -f inputfile | sed -n -e 's/0/X/g p')`  That works by itself, but when I pipe the output to something else (like `tee`) it only prints `Start` and then hangs.  It definitely feels like buffering.
Update: it _is_ buffering -- after letting it sit for a while, `tee` printed a bunch of stuff, and it was about 4096 bytes worth.  I think `sed` must be checking whether its output is a terminal, and buffering if not.

Comment: If your `sed` supports the `-u` (unbuffered) option, try that.  Works for me on Debian-8, sed-4.2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buffering problem was resolved when I prefixed the sed command with the following:

```
stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0
```

Much more preferable to using unbuffer, which didn't even work for me. Dave M's suggestion of using sed's relatively new -u also seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you may be getting confused by -- `|` (pipeline) is higher precedence than `&&` (consecutive execution).  So when you say

```
(echo "new" && tail -f ~/inputfile 2> /dev/null | sed -n -r 'some regex' && cat) | ./program
```

that is equivalent to

```
(echo "new" && (tail -f ~/inputfile 2> /dev/null | sed -n -r 'some regex') && cat) | ./program
```

So the `cat` isn't really doing anything, and the `sed` output is probably buffered a bit.  You can try using the `-u` option to `sed` to get it to use unbuffered output:

```
(echo "new" && (tail -f ~/inputfile 2> /dev/null | sed -n -u -r 'some regex')) | ./program
```

I believe some versions of `sed` default to `-u` when the output is a terminal and not when it is a pipe, so that may be the source of the difference you're seeing.

Comment: Using `& cat` instead of `&& cat` gave me the result i was looking for: the ability to simultaneously pipe input into a program and interact with it using the keyboard.

Comment: `& cat` means run the previous pipeline (tail | sed) in the background, while running `cat` in the foreground -- totally different from `&&`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `i` command in `sed` (see the command list in the manpage for details) to do the inserting at the beginning:

```
tail -f inputfile | sed -e '1inew file' -e 's/this/that/' | ./program
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're recommending here, I tried adding the `i` command with no extra success